# What are the roles of "Game theory" and "optimisation (linear, integer, conic)" in Finance, Mathematical Finance?

Tags: optimization, theory, game

Would you please give me some information about application of "Game theory" and "Optimisation" in Finance and Mathematical Finance? which is more important to know and learn?
How about "multi-criteria decision making" and "non-linear programming"?

Any suggestions and advice are welcome.

Thank you in advance.
Seer

Comment: How is this seeking career advice?

Comment: Sorry, I do not seek career advice, just want to know which aspect has been more highlighted in Math Finance or the importance of each in math finance. Thanks

Comment: user7985, @Bob Jansen flagged your question as off-topic because it is a question "seeking career advice", but I do not think this is "seeking career advice"

Comment: Presumably you want to know this because you want to start a career in Quantitative Finance? The guidance in the [tour] applies, as it is a version of "How do I become a quant?" There are some good reasons that we don't want this kind of question, see this question on meta: http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/13/idea-about-education-questions/14#14